# How to cache stored procedure with Doctrine

Tags: php, caching, doctrine, procedure

I have a complex stored procedure that is run multiple times on a site developed in php. I have Doctrine on the system (I'm not a doctrine guru) from the previous developer. The stored procedure takes about 4.62 seconds to run and return results. I would like to cache the results but am unfamiliar with caching with Doctrine. The results are limited to 200 with 25 per page. One of my concerns is that the data can change often, so not sure how to get the site faster. Thanks.

EDIT

---

I found the files I was missing for Doctrine\Common\Cache and uploaded them.

I have the following function; however, it is not caching:

```
function getGeo($latitude, $longitude, $radius, $numResults, $volunteerPid, $startPosition, $pageSize)
    {
        $cacheDriver = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
        if ($numResults == 5) {
            if ($cacheDriver->contains($volunteerPid)) {
                $geoQuery = $cacheDriver->fetch($volunteerPid);
                echo "Number results equals 5 and has cache";
            } else {
                $geoQuery = $this->connection->prepare("call sproc_qryGeoPrecint($latitude, $longitude, $radius, $numResults, $volunteerPid, $startPosition, $pageSize)");
                $cacheDriver->save($volunteerPid, $geoQuery);
                echo "Number results equals 5 and has NO cache";
            }
        } else {
            if ($cacheDriver->contains($volunteerPid)) {
                $geoQuery = $cacheDriver->fetch($volunteerPid);
                echo "Number results equals 200 and has cache";
            } else {
                $geoQuery = $this->connection->prepare("call sproc_qryGeoPrecint($latitude, $longitude, $radius, $numResults, $volunteerPid, $startPosition, $pageSize)");
                $cacheDriver->save($volunteerPid, $geoQuery);
                echo "Number results equals 200 and has NO  cache";
            }
        }
        return $geoQuery;
    }
```

Comment: The ArrayCache just stores data in memory so it won't persist across requests, I think it mostly exists for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the [Doctrine result cache](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache). You can configure the query that executes the stored procedure to use the result cache. If the data changes often you can set a short lifetime for the cache and/or set up an event listener to invalidate the cache when relevant data is changed.

Comment: For my result set, I have the following line:

`return $this->connection->prepare("call sproc_qryGeo($latitude, $longitude, $radius, $startPosition, $pageSize)");`

How would I write `$query->useResultCache(true);` for the above line to use the cache instead of hitting the stored procedure again?

Comment: I don't have `Doctrine\Common\Cache\` folder. I'm not sure what version of Doctrine I'm running. How can I tell?

Comment: Looks like the other developer installed 2.6 dev on the server. The link that you gave has example that uses the Doctrine/Common/Cache folder, which is non-existent on my server. Should I have that folder or is there another way to cache?

Comment: Do I need apc installed in order to use result cache?

Comment: Only if you want to use the ApcCache provider. There are a bunch of different providers (https://github.com/doctrine/cache/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache). The simplest one to get up and running might be the FilesystemCache, as you wouldn't need to install anything or set up e.g. a redis instance.